# change window title with python on script start

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I put together a simple script to encode movies, now while the script works just fine I am having difficulties on changing the window title on script start instead on when its terminated. since is kind of useless to mark each window after it finished. can I use subprocess to perform such task? so change the title while the script runs?

I am using this in a bash script to change the title:

```
PS1="\e]2;$1\a\[$1 \W]\$"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the sub process without invoking any new terminal , you can rename the windows with below code

```
# your subprocess code here
import sys
sys.stdout.write(b'\33]0;title you want\a')
```

Comment: I tried this code, I saw it on another question I put it inside a file.py but did not do anything. However, if I type python and put that code inside the python shell it works.